# Creating a lightning compatible button that runs an apex method

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

So it's simple i have a list button on an object that executes JS to do

```
updatePeripherals()
```

Which simply runs an apex method.

Now my solution would just be to create a VF page that runs the script and assign that to a lightning quick action. IE create a button to work in lighting on the standard related list of a record. Now i add SVC_CR_Package_Ctl because the method i want to run is in that apex class.

```
<apex:page standardController="SVC_Operations__c" extensions="SVC_CR_Package_Ctl" >
    <apex:form >
        <script>
        updatePeripherals()

        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Which hopefully would run this method, which is part of a global with sharing class.

```
public PageReference updatePeripherals()
{
    try {
        SVC_PKG_Service.deployPeripherals(this.packageObj.Id, this.packageObj.Change_Request__r.Account__c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e, null, 'Deployment failed');
    }

    // page refresh is required because we need to refresh related lists (which cannot be rerenderd) and package header (which also cannot be rerendered)
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/SVC_CR_Package?id=' + this.packageObj.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

Now you can see in the try it runs another method in a different class, which is a public with sharing class SVC_PKG_Service. This one also has multiple methods on multiple objects.

Cool easy right, not really. Because I'm realizing this is a list button. Meant to be on the related list of another object, but it does not need "Display Checkboxes (for Multi-Record Selection)". But when i try to create a list button that would run by VF page...there's nothing their, it appears as an option everywhere else but not there.

What am i missing, also would it be better to make this a lightning component instead...? Can a lightning component do what i want without having to put in loads of dev time (because i have to convert like 40 other buttons just like this, so i'm looking for the easiest way of getting this working in lightning)

EDIT: now that i thought about it for five seconds i'll probably just do  `action="{!updatePeripherals()}">` or something on the page but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that will help with your approach:

1) To call an apex function from VF you don't use javascript. You can either add a button in the page (`<apex:commandButton action="{! updatePeripherals}" value="Update"/>`), call it using an `actionFunction` (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm?search_text=actionfunction)) or add it on the action (onload) of your page (`<apex:page action="{! updatePeripherals}"..../>`)

2) In order to be able to add a VF page to a List button, you must implement the standard controller. I won't copy the entire answer, but [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/list-button-doesnt-see-visualforce-page) SFSE answer explains it in detail

You have to add `<apex:page standardController="YourObject__c" recordSetVar="yourRecords">`, even if you do not plan to use the functionality that the standard controller provides.