# Add Custom VF Button to OpportunityContactRoles Related List

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, related-list, opportunitycontactrole

Evening,

I'm attempting to launch a Screen Flow from a VisualForce Page on a related list for OpportunityContactRoles. The flow will be a guided process for ContactRoles.

The Related List for the OCRs is on the Opportunity Layout.

Here is the code for the visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="OpportunityContactRole">
    <flow:interview name="TestFLOW"/>
</apex:page>
```

Here is a screen shot of my view when I attempt to add it (SideNote: recordSetVar="oppRoles" is not supported on OCRs).

[image]

### Research:

[Article from Stack Exchange On Visualforce and RelatedLists](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/list-button-doesnt-see-visualforce-page)

Answer (score 0):

list button need an recordSetVar attribute in the page to control selected records from the list in order to see the Visualforce try to add recordSetVar="record"

```
    <apex:page standardController="OpportunityContactRole" recordSetVar="record">
         <flow:interview name="TestFLOW"/>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks @mohammadAl-Said but, "recordSetVar" is not a supported variable on OpportunityContactRoles.